# Close InputStream after renderBinary() call in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework

In the Play framework there is a render method called `renderBinary` where it is possible to render an `InputStream`.

It was my understanding that no code is run after the renderBinary() method call, so how do we go about closing the `InputStream`?

Take the following example:

```
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try{
        //create temp file
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile( "foobar", ".txt" );

        inputStream = new FileInputStream( tempFile );

        //delete temp file
        tempFile.delete();

        //download the file as held in the inputstream
        renderBinary( inputStream, foobar + ".txt" );
    }
    catch( Exception e ){
        throw e;
    }
    finally {
        if( inputStream != null )
            inputStream.close();
    }
```

Would this be a suitable way of closing the `InputStream` or would `finally` never get called?

I know there will be a 'try it and see' answer, and I have tried it and I do not get any '*out of memory*' errors when I repeatedly download big files in quick sucession - but I do not know how I could go about checking whether the `InputStream` has actually closed.

Comment: Is it safe to delete the file after opening a connection to that file using FileInputStream? If the file is larger than 8KB, wouldn't the subsequent 'read' on the InputStream give an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the [source code](https://github.com/playframework/play) of the class that [implements](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/mvc/results/RenderBinary.java) that code, it is closed. I really recommend downloading the source and linking it to your project, Play does some "magic" behind the scenes which is good to see :)

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. It is interesting to see that play does indeed close the `InputStream`. I will definately check the documentation more carefully in the future as Play does have a lot of tricks up its sleaves!